# Nginx, SSL and OSCP

Tags: nginx, ssl, ocsp

I have a problem. When I open my website with https, I see error message in my error.log:

```
2015/11/03 19:47:21 [error] 7799#0: recv() failed (111: Connection refused) while requesting certificate status, responder: ocsp2.globalsign.com
2015/11/03 19:47:21 [error] 7799#0: OCSP responder prematurely closed connection while requesting certificate status, responder: ocsp2.globalsign.com
```

How can I solve it? 
BR

Answer (score 0):

It seems that these are temporary issues on let's encrypt the infrastructure side. I've seen them few times but then this error disappears.

Answer (score -1):

Disable OCSP stapling or permit your nginx server to access the OCSP responder.